# How do you set a default for Swashbuckle BodyParam v4.0.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, default, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-2.2

So I basically have a signature like this:

```
[HttpGet, Route("widget/{widgetId}"), ResponseType(typeof(Widget))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetWidgetWithValues([FromQuery] DashboardFilters filters, int widgetId = 1024)
```

With a POCO of DashboardFilters like so:

```
public class DashboardFilters
{
    [DefaultValue("6/1/2019")]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> UniversityIds { get; set; }
    [SwaggerDefaultValue("Test", "Hello there")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried setting 'DefaultValue' and a 'SwaggerDefaultValueAttribute'

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    internal class SwaggerDefaultValueAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public SwaggerDefaultValueAttribute(string parameterName, object value) => (this.ParameterName, this.Value) = (parameterName, value);

        public string ParameterName { get; private set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Basically nothing works.  I can set a header param quite easy still with this:

```
public class SwaggerAddAuthHeader : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
            operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();

        operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            Description = "JWT",
            In = "header",
            Type = "string",
            Default = "Bearer "
        });

    }
}
```

And wire that up to the swaggerGet like so:

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
        {
            x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = $"Admin API", Version = "v1", Description = $"Last updated: {settings.General.DateUpdated}" });

            //This enables the /// comments on each method to be used better for swagger
            x.IncludeXmlComments(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.Replace(".dll", ".xml"));
            x.OperationFilter<SwaggerAddAuthHeader>();
        });
```

I tried to add something for a 'BodyParameter' in the SwaggerAddAuthHeader and the 'default' property is gone.  Has anyone run into this?  It seems very strange you would not have a means to define defaults for complex types.  Yes I am aware with simple primitives you can generate their defaults as I did above.

Comment: DefaultValue should work... How does your swagger.json looks like?

Comment: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#/Company/Company_Get2 are those defaults what you are looking for?  the code for that is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/c9b554fde26367418c84fcd3682d308ae1b40d11/Swagger_Test/Models/Company.cs

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am using 4.0.1 with .NET Core 2.2.  I see on your github you are setting the 'default' attribute and using .NET Full Framework. 
 I do that and it does nothing.  It completely ignores that.  I even tried Default Value as well.  It will work if I do a signature set like MyRouteMethod(int id = 10).  10 will then be shown but if I do it on complex DTOs it will not work.

Comment: that should be working they even have unittests for it:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/search?q=foobar&unscoped_q=foobar&type=Code
report it as a bug and provide a clear reproducible example